# Use GET request for form submission in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, get, jsf-2

Is there a way to submit a form and have the URL include the parameters, that is submit as a GET request.. rather than POST?

form.jsf/?firstName=John&lastName=Doe

I thought  would work (instead of the normal , however it doesn't seem to grab the form data.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can with preRenderViewEvent 
you can have something like this in view

```
 <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="team" value="#{teamEditView.team}"/>
 </f:metadata>
 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{teamEditView.setupEditPage}"/>
```

where you can pas view params and invoke the listener and fetch data acording to params in that listener method.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the action of the form to be get instead of post.  This will add the form values to the qs instead of posting them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<h:form>` by `<form>` and use either `@ManagedProperty` in the model side or `<f:viewParam>` in the view side to set those parameters as bean properties.